Spark on Dataproc: Slow Data Insertion into BigQuery for Large Datasets (~30M Records)
I have a Scala Spark job running on Google Cloud Dataproc that sources and writes data to Google BigQuery (BQ) tables. The code works fine for smaller datasets, but when processing larger volumes (e.g., ~30M records), it takes an excessive amount of time to load the final BQ tables.
Problem Summary:
My Spark job follows these steps:
Extract data: Join multiple tables to produce an initial dataset.
Transform data: Iterate over the dataset using the map function, apply two different transformations, and generate two separate datasets.
Compare, filter and load: Cross-compare the two datasets, apply filters, and then insert the results into two separate BQ tables.
Code Snippet:
Below is a simplified version of the code used in step 2:
case class Reconresult(/* define the schema of Reconresult */)
case class Reconsource(/* define the schema of Reconsource */)

// Step 1: Perform the transformation to get a Dataset of tuples (Reconresult, Reconsource)
val transformedDS: Dataset[(Reconresult, Reconsource)] = inputtransformedDS.map { a =>
  val reconsult = transformationReconsult(a)
  val reconsource = transformationReconsource(a)
  (reconsult, reconsource)
}

// Step 2: Separate the transformed Dataset into two DataFrames
val reconsultDF: DataFrame = transformedDS.map(_._1).toDF()
val reconsourceDF: DataFrame = transformedDS.map(_._2).toDF()

// Return the two DataFrames as a tuple
(reconsultDF, reconsourceDF)

Issue:
All steps execute correctly until it comes time to persist the data. Due to Spark's lazy evaluation, the actual work occurs when I try to insert the data into the final BQ tables, which causes the job to take hours to complete.
Things I’ve Tried:
Combining transformations: I tried returning a single dataset from step 2 by combining the results of both transformations. When I do this, the entire process (including data insertion) completes in about 15 minutes, even when filtering and inserting data into the final table.
Question:
Why does splitting the transformations and inserting data into two separate BQ tables take so long compared to combining the transformations into a single dataset? Is there a more efficient way to handle this process in Spark, especially when dealing with large datasets?

I'm guessing that what you are doing looks like this. If you observe here, creating two dataframes leads to branching in the DAG and each branch will start its processing from the root and not the parent node (if no result caching is done).
Things that you can try:

Here you can use df = df.cache() or df = df.persist() depending upon the data size and compute and memory resources.
You can use broadcast while joining.
You can use Big Query Storage API to speed things up. Use this example.


The 2nd example that you are trying will look like this. Here there is a single branch that is getting processed so the time is actually less.

Possible starting points to debug if the problem still persists:

Look into job's logical and physical plan (use Spark UI for this).
If the DAG looks very complicated then try to simplify it.
Simplify by breaking the processes and saving the intermediate results.

